# Как подсчитать общее кол-во баллов с таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Имею таблицу, где записывается имя и очки пользователей, например:

1. login:score
2. user_1 12
3. user_1 54
4. user_2 2

и т.д
Мне нужно сделать запрос mysqli_query, чтобы он подсчитал все очки, где `login` = 'user_1' к примеру
Следовательно он мне должен выдать число 66.

Answer (score 3):

Запрос будет таким:

```
SELECT SUM(`score`) as `total` FROM `table` WHERE `login` = 'user_1'
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает